# How to replace all occurrences of an element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Consider the following:

```
list={1,2,2,2,3};
```

I would like to replace all `2` with the string "Test". `Replace[list,2->"Test"]` does not do it.

Result must be: `{1,"Test","Test","Test",3}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
list /. {2 -> "Test"}

(* Out[]:= {1, "Test", "Test", "Test", 3} *)
```

Comment: Internally, `a /. b` becomes `ReplaceAll[a,b]` which by default, replaces all instances found.

Comment: I prefere this one at the moment, as you can replace different figures at the same time, e.g. `list/.{1->"A",2->"X"}`. I wounder whether `Replace` is able of that too?

Comment: @John It is: `Replace[list, {1 -> "B", 2 -> "Test"}, {1}]`

Comment: @John note, that once a match is found, it stops looking, and refuses to apply a sequence of replacements, e.g. `a /. {a -> b, b -> c}` returns `b`. But, you can use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) (`//.`), instead. `a //. {a -> b, b -> c}` then returns `c`.

Answer (score 10):

`Replace` by default works on the whole expression. You can add a level specification

```
list={1,2,2,2,3};
Replace[list,2->"Test", {1}]
```

Gives

```
{1, "Test", "Test", "Test", 3}
```

Answer (score 7):

For example:

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3};
list /. {2 -> "test"}
If[# == 2, "test", #] & /@ list
Replace[list, 2 -> "test", 1]
ReplacePart[list, Position[list, 2] -> "test"]
```