# Replace values which obey certain criteria

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I'd like to replace all values in a list which obey one or more criteria with another value.

Example: Replace all `values>30` by $30$.

```
data={{3,35},{2,7}}
```

Afterwards it should be:

> {{3,30},{2,7}}

Example #2:

```
aa= {300., 150., 100., 76.8421, 64.0909, 55.567, 49.1935, 44.2262, 
    40.2247, 36.9355, 34.1667, 31.8138, 29.7887, 28.0087, 26.4537, 
    25.0612, 23.8186, 22.7059, 21.6854, 20.7663, 19.9265, 19.1519, 
    18.4323, 17.7739, 17.1672, 16.6007, 16.0648, 15.5605, 15.098}
```

If a value of `aa` is greater than 100 I want to replace it with an arbitrary value, e.g. 50.

Comment: `data /. x_ /; x > 30 -> 30` ?

Comment: Alternatively you can write it functionally as, 

`Map[Min[#,30]&,data,{2}]`   or 
`Map[If[#<30,#,30]&,data,{2}]`

Comment: Only for the one criterium: `Clip[{{3, 35}, {2, 7}}, {-Infinity, 30}]`

Comment: ...or `data /. x_ -> Min[x, 30]`.

Comment: ...thanks for the fast answers and the different solutions. Nice to have a solution using Map as well as one with patterns ;-)

Comment: With all due respect to all involved, why answering in comments? The question is (IMO) borderline RTFM, which is probably why people used comments. But it would IMO be better if one either decides to answer and puts an answer or decides to close and puts a close vote. Comments are generally not intended to replace answers.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I agree. I've voted to close as TL now, but the OP is welcome to use the comments above to write an answer with the different approaches with explanations. It might also be a good learning experience for them (cc: rainer)

Comment: @R.M. I don't have a strong opinion on whether or not this particular question is TL (RTFM), although I am more inclined to consider it as such. I just think that we should not create a gray area and a precedent for treating such borderline cases in this way (answering in comments), we need to stay sharp.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I guess TL might not actually be necessary, in light of open questions like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4488/5) (which I think should be closed). From a certain point of view, most list-manipulation questions are TL anyway, but we shouldn't be closing them if there's an opportunity to learn something. In any case, I agree that we should be creating gray areas.

Comment: @rainer Please consider answering this question yourself with what you've learnt from the comments above and try to make it comprehensive with examples and commentary

Comment: @R.M. Rather than closing such questions, I would keep them for some time, and then at some point write a meta-question about replacements, providing some general view. Then, those questions can be closed (but not deleted) with links to that meta-question added to them.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm not advocating closing... I don't think this should be closed, as I mentioned, if the OP (or someone) were to write an answer. The other one that I linked to, probably ought to have been because it is probably found from the first search result in the doc center (although it's too late now to draw any attention and I don't like digging old stuff just for the sake of it). I like the idea of the meta-question covering all bases, but it's all a matter of time and effort and everyone's short of it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Up front you have a choice between pattern-based and numeric manipulation of an array.  Pattern-based is more general; numeric is usually fastest when applicable.

```
a = {{21, 95, 50}, {39, 32, 76}, {9, 12, 75}};
```

Examples of pattern based methods:

```
a /. n_Integer /; n > 30 -> 30

a /. n_?NumericQ /; n > 30 -> 30

Replace[a, n_?(#>30&) -> 30, {2}]
```

Examples of numeric methods:

```
Clip[a, {-∞, 30}]

(a - 30) UnitStep[30 - a] + 30
```

Other, less desirable methods:

```
If[# > 30, 30, #, #] & //@ a

Map[#~Min~30 &, a, {-1}]
```

---

Fast numeric methods for the second example:

```
Clip[aa, {-∞, 100}, {0, 50.}]

(1 - #) 50. + aa # & @ UnitStep[100 - aa]
```

Comment: Holy <unprintable>! When did you hit 30k? Congrats!

Comment: @rcollyer lol -- a couple of days ago.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: Well, that serves me right for not paying attention.

Answer (score 10):

```
aa = {300., 150., 100., 76.8421, 64.0909, 55.567, 49.1935, 44.2262, 
   40.2247, 36.9355, 34.1667, 31.8138, 29.7887, 28.0087, 26.4537, 
   25.0612, 23.8186, 22.7059, 21.6854, 20.7663, 19.9265, 19.1519, 
   18.4323, 17.7739, 17.1672, 16.6007, 16.0648, 15.5605, 15.098};

ReplacePart[aa, Position[aa, x_ /; x > 100] -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Testing results for different size vectors

**Summary:**

`ReplacePart` is the slowest. `Clip` is fastest as well as having linear performance with size of problem (10 times as long a vector, 10 times as much CPU) which is a good thing (TM). It was also faster than Matlab's `find`.

**Report**

Since there are timings being done (good thing), I thought I add Matlab's timing for this, on same PC I have to compare. Used Matlab's `tic` and `toc` which measures the elapsed time. This corresponds to Mathematica's `AbsoluteTiming`

```
EDU>> help tic
 tic Start a stopwatch timer.
    tic and TOC functions work together to measure elapsed time.
```

This is full results of all tests (thanks for input from others) for vector sizes of `1,000,000` and `10,000,000` and `100,000,000` (I have lots of RAM and lots of coffee so it is ok :)

This all were done on windows 7, using Mathematica 9.01 on 64 bit OS and PC. 16 GB RAM. Matlab is `2013a` version. 32 bit.

Here is the code used to generate all these tables

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
size = 1000000; (*change this to change the vector size *)
aa = RandomInteger[400, size];
examples = {HoldForm[
    ReplacePart[aa, Position[aa, x_ /; x > 100] -> 50.]; //AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[If[# > 100, 50., #] & /@ aa; // AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[Replace[aa, x_ /; x > 100 -> 50., 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[Clip[aa, {-100., 100.}, {0., 50.}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[Clip[aa, {-\[Infinity], 100.}, {0., 50.}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[Clip[aa, {-\[Infinity], 100}, {0, 50.}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First],
   HoldForm[With[{t = UnitStep[100 - aa]}, (1 - t) 50. + t aa];//AbsoluteTiming//First]
   };
res = {#, ReleaseHold[#]} & /@ examples;
Grid[AppendTo[
  res, {" clear all; a=randi(400,1000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; \
toc", 0.0155}], Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, 
 Spacings -> {0.5, 1}, FrameStyle -> LightGray]
```

**1,000,000**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,1000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 0.015441 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,1000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 0.018643 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,1000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 0.014538 seconds.
```

**10,000,000**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,10000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 0.149870 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,10000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 0.150574 seconds.
```

**100,000,000**

After few hrs, the full table was still not completed and all memory was used and with no way to know how long it will take, had to stop the computation so that I can use the PC. Removed the first test, which turned out to be the case of the problem. Now the table builds fast. Here it is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,100000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 1.496174 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,100000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 1.496570 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,100000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 1.501019 seconds.
```

**150,000,000**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,150000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 2.240782 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,150000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 2.241474 seconds.
EDU>> clear all; a=randi(400,150000000,1);  tic; a(find(a>100))=50; toc
Elapsed time is 2.244419 seconds.
```

Comment: Note that some of the results look drastically different for real numbers (at least on my machine). Maybe you could incorporate that too...

Comment: I guess it depends what you call drastic. You have a difference of about a factor 10 for the 2nd version (`If`) and the 6th version (last `Clip`). For me the speedup for `Clip` is even a bit more than a factor 20.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't take a closer look at the various `Clip` versions. Just figured out that the difference is just a conversion from integers to reals. That explains the difference of course :) So I guess you are right and it is not so notable after all.

Comment: I my god!. You do not know losing! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options:

```
aa = {300., 150., 100., 76.8421, 64.0909, 55.567, 49.1935, 44.2262, 
   40.2247, 36.9355, 34.1667, 31.8138, 29.7887, 28.0087, 26.4537, 
   25.0612, 23.8186, 22.7059, 21.6854, 20.7663, 19.9265, 19.1519, 
   18.4323, 17.7739, 17.1672, 16.6007, 16.0648, 15.5605, 15.098};

If[# > 100, 50, #] & /@ aa
Replace[aa, x_ /; x > 100 -> 50, {1}]
```

Some performance tests:

```
aa=RandomInteger[400,1000000];
nasser01 = ReplacePart[aa,Position[list,x_/;x>100]->50];//AbsoluteTiming//First
murta01  = If[#>100,50,#]&/@aa;//AbsoluteTiming//First
murta02  = Replace[aa,x_/;x>100->50,{1}];//AbsoluteTiming//First

nasser01 = 2.636266
murta01  = 0.052457
murta02  = 0.537735
```

Answer (score 4):

```
With[{t = UnitStep[100 - aa]}, (1 - t) 50 + t aa]
Table[If[i > 100, 50, i], {i, aa}]
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines, +1. It's not faster though I think.

Answer (score 3):

In any case here is a `Clip` solution

```
Clip[aa, {-∞, 100}, {0, 50.}]
```

...which is not as fast as `UnitStep` on my machine ...unless you ensure you use all reals

```
Clip[aa, {-100., 100.}, {0., 50.}]

aa = RandomInteger[400, 100000];
tmp1 = ReplacePart[aa, Position[aa, x_ /; x > 100] -> 50.]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp2 = If[# > 100, 50., #] & /@ aa; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp3 = Replace[aa, x_ /; x > 100 -> 50., 1]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp4 = Clip[aa, {-100., 100.}, {0., 50.}]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp5 = Clip[aa, {-∞, 100.}, {0., 50.}]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp6 = Clip[aa, {-∞, 100}, {0, 50.}]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
tmp7 = With[{t = UnitStep[100 - aa]}, (1 - t) 50. + t aa]; //AbsoluteTiming // First
```

[image]

So on my machine this quite a bit faster than others