# Speeding Up Replacing of Labels in Large Matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, performance-tuning, image-processing

I am Mathematica novice and am trying to find a fast way to replace labels in some rather large matrices (512x512 or 1024x1024)  that have resulted from segmenting images with WatershedComponents or MorphologicalComponents.  At present I have written the function below that takes a "label matrix" (matrix that results from segmentation) and a list of "keeper" labels (labels that I want to remain in place in the returned matrix) and returns a new matrix with only those labels remaining in place that are in the listOfKeepersIn.  All other labels are replaced in the returned matrix with a single "background" label, here designated as 100.

I suspect there are many more efficient ways to achieve this than what I have written here, so I welcome your suggestions.  I have tried to convert this to a Compiled Function using Compile but haven't had any success (get an error message about "tensors of different ranks").  I also tried to use ParallelTable instead of Table but didn't notice much improvement.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. -GR

```
ComponentKeeperFunction[matrixIn_, listOfKeepersIn_] :=

Block[{matrixToReturn},

matrixToReturn = 

Table[

 Which[

      MemberQ[listOfKeepersIn, matrixIn[[r, c]]] == True,

    (* If label value is on the keeper list then just keep that
    label in its place, (i.e. make the value in the table the same as    
    matrixIn[[r,c]])*)

    matrixIn[[r, c]], 


    MemberQ[listOfKeepersIn, matrixIn[[r, c]]] == False,

    (* If label value is not on the keeper list then replace that label with a          
     designated background label  *)        

    100  (*here I designate the background label as having a value of 100 *)

 ] (* close Which *),


{r, 1, Dimensions[matrixIn][[1]]}, {c, 1, Dimensions[matrixIn][[2]]}

 ] (*close Table *);

  Return[matrixToReturn]

 ](*close Block*)
```

Comment: You can remove `matrixToReturn =` and `Return[matrixToReturn`. If you do not put a semicolon at the end of `Table` it will return its result automatically. Also `Module` is recommended rather than `Block`, which you can read about [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs). Overall, using `Table` like this is typical for someone with a background in procedural languages, but *Mathematica* is faster with functional programming so you should try to use corresponding functional alternatives, such as `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Good to know about not needing to explicitly Return since then I don't need to use Block or Module as much. -GR

Answer (score 3):

In order to apply a function to every element we can use `Map` with the level specification:

```
Map[If[MemberQ[keep, #], #, 100] &, matrix, {2}]
```

Another option using the `Listable` attribute:

```
Function[{x}, If[MemberQ[keep, x], x, 100], Listable]@matrix;
```

This turned out to be a lot slower though. I ran these on Michael E2's test case and the `Listable` approach took 13.87 seconds to complete, while the `Map` version took only 0.34 seconds. But Michael E2's compiled `Listable` approach is faster than both.

Answer (score 3):

`SelectComponents` is pretty fast but it labels the background with `0`, not `100`.  You might be able to work with that.

```
SelectComponents[mat, "Label", MemberQ[keep, #] &]
```

but this is a bit faster:

```
sel = Compile[{{label, _Integer}, {keep, _Integer, 1}},
  If[MemberQ[keep, label], label, 0],  (* or 100 if necessary *)
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

Example

```
mat = MorphologicalComponents @ Binarize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "U2"}], 0.2];
Dimensions@mat
Max[mat]
(*
  {1024, 1024}  -- dimensions
  1923          -- number of components
*)

SeedRandom[1];
keep = RandomSample[Range@Max[mat], Round[Max[mat]/10]]
(*
  {1675, 29, 17, 1552, 1697, 1826, 1022, 1568, 138, 1203, 1085, 1539, 
   ... 713, 114, 567, 656, 1747, 134, 94}
*)
SelectComponents[mat, "Label", MemberQ[keep, #] &]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.739382, Null}
*)

sel[mat, keep]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.282210, Null}
*)
```

If I compile to C (`CompilationTarget -> "C"`), I save another 20% in timing.

If `keep` is about half of the components, then the timings rise to 2.5 sec. and 0.9 sec. respectively.  If `keep` is larger, it would be more efficient to take its complement and delete.

Comment: Thanks very much!  SelectComponents is quite a bit faster and seeing a Compile example I can make work is helpful. Can you suggest any similar methods to efficiently join one or more components to another component?  -GR

Comment: @user13999 I think you just have to give them the same label (integer), somewhat like the reverse of the compiled function `sel`.  In a sense, `sel` joins all the non-`keep` components to the background.  Just switch the logic, `If[MemberQ[join, label], Min[join], label]`, where `join` is a list of components to join.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion, I have a joinComponents function working along these lines now and it is much faster than what I was doing before.

Comment: Btw, one thing I am still wondering is if there is some way to use SparseArray or something similar to store the final segmentation mask (i.e. store the resulting label matrix after finishing using joinComponents and SelectComponents or your "sel" function) so it does not take up so much memory (I am doing this for several hundred timelapse images).  The actual components of interest typically take up between 5% to 25% of the whole mask so there's a lot of background in each mask. -GR

Answer (score 2):

I shall not attempt to replicate the exact function of your code but rather to address the problem posed in text of your Question.

As a starting point I suggest you build a [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) table of the replacements you wish to make and then apply it with [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html).

First some sample data:

```
SeedRandom[0]
m = RandomInteger[66, {1024, 1024}];

keep = Array[Prime, 18];
```

`keep` is my label list; I chose prime numbers merely as an example.

Now build the `Dispatch` table:

```
rules = Append[Thread[keep -> keep], _ -> 100] // Dispatch;
```

And apply it:

```
(result = Replace[m, rules, {2}];) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.187201
> ```

Check the result with a [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html):

```
result // Flatten // Tally
```

> ```
> {{100, 766948}, {43, 15736}, {17, 15664}, {53, 15823}, {19, 15503}, {31, 15726}, {5, 
>   15609}, {37, 15492}, {11, 15713}, {13, 15687}, {59, 15828}, {41, 15837}, {29, 
>   15722}, {47, 15552}, {2, 15519}, {23, 15648}, {61, 15590}, {7, 15435}, {3, 15544}}
> ```

If all of your keep labels are in a sequential band there are much faster numeric methods easily applicable.  See: [Replace values which obey certain criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9719/121)

Comment: Wow, yet another way to do this!  I'll give it a try, never came across the Dispatch function before.  Also, thanks for the link. -GR