# Replacing pairs of values under constraints in a large nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, replacement

I have a list of integers that looks e.g.

```
t = {{{1170, 4150}, {1883, 7089}, {2105, 7704}}, {{2413, 8086}, {1928,
     7764}, {2126, 8312}}, {{3791, 10052}, {9832, 21949}, {10367, 
    23078}}}
```

I want to replace those value pairs that fall into a certain range (e.g. first element between 1000 and 2000 and second element between 3000 and 8000). The entire element should be replaced by e.g. Red. With the just mentioned criteria, the result should be:

```
t = {{Red, Red, {2105, 7704}}, {{2413, 8086},Red, {2126, 8312}}, {{3791, 10052}, {9832, 21949}, {10367,23078}}}
```

Now, the actual list is massive, thousands to millions of entries – it's an image. I've used multiple attempts and either failed (when trying using ReplacePart), or the code takes ages (when using If conditions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
t /. {a_ /; 1000 < a < 2000, b_ /; 3000 < b < 8000} -> Red
```

> ```
> {{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {2105, 7704}}, {{2413, 8086}, 
>   RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {2126, 8312}}, {{3791, 10052}, {9832, 21949}, {10367, 23078}}}
> ```

which is the way it outputs on my machine because Red is a built-in symbol.

Answer (score 4):

You my use [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelMap.html). Read the [Parallel Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ParallelEvaluation.html) tutorial.

Using

```
t = RandomInteger[{500, 10000}, {100000, 3, 2}];
```

With

```
foo =
 If[
   Between[{1000, 2000}]@First@# && Between[{3000, 8000}]@Last@#,
   Red,
   #] &;
```

Then

```
new = ParallelMap[foo, t, {2}];
```

Will fill `new` with the replaced data having performed the replacement in parallel over the launched kernels. Number of kernels depends on your configuration and license.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you using Apply here? `And[a, b]` will short-circuit, ie return False immediately if a is False. `And@@{a, b}` will compute both a and b first, it's less efficient.

Comment: @SimonWoods Good point! (+1) Updated.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a more complex version of [Replace values which obey certain criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9719/121) and the same principles apply: if you want a *fast* operation look for vectorized numeric approaches.

Since you want to operate on the first element of each pair separately from the second element we may want to separate those first using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
{t1, t2} = Transpose[t, {2, 3, 1}];
```

Since we are looking for values in a certain range method from [SO 6026827](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6026827/618728) can apply.

Since performance is the goal I shall use explicit `Subtract`; re: [(40927)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121)

```
between = UnitStep[Subtract[#, #2]*Subtract[#3, #]] &;
```

This function produces a binary (zero or one) result and it is inherently [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html).

Therefore our replacement mask can be produced with `Times` taking the role of And:

```
mask = between[t1, 1000, 2000] * between[t2, 3000, 8000]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
> ```

The [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) property [`"AdjacencyLists"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83721/121) is a fast way to get the positions `1` in each row:

```
pos = SparseArray[mask]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {2}, {}}
> ```

*Revision: an analysis of the first function I posted revealed that [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) was a performance bottleneck, therefore I am replacing it with a [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) assignment.*

Row by row this can be used for replacement like this:

```
row = t[[1]];
row[[{1, 2}]] = Red;
row
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {2105, 7704}}
> ```

As a self-contained function:

```
f2[t_, new_, {lo1_, hi1_}, {lo2_, hi2_}] :=
   Module[{t1, t2, between, mask, pos, row},
     {t1, t2} = Transpose[t, {2, 3, 1}];
     between = UnitStep[Subtract[#, #2]*Subtract[#3, #]] &;
     mask = between[t1, lo1, hi1]*between[t2, lo2, hi2];
     pos = SparseArray[mask]["AdjacencyLists"];
     MapThread[(row = #; row[[#2]] = new; row) &, {t, pos}]
   ];

f2[t, Red, {1000, 2000}, {3000, 8000}]
```

> ```
> {{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {2105, 7704}},
>  {{2413, 8086}, RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {2126, 8312}},
>  {{3791, 10052}, {9832, 21949}, {10367, 23078}}}
> ```

This is quite a bit faster than bobbym's admittedly simpler [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) code:

```
big = RandomInteger[9000, {3000, 3000, 2}];

f2[big, Red, {1000, 2000}, {3000, 8000}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {1.745, Null}
> ```

```
big /. {a_ /; 1000 < a < 2000, b_ /; 3000 < b < 8000} -> Red; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {9.03, Null}
> ```

Comment: You are correct, yours is much faster +1. Let me be the first to congratulate you for reaching 200k rep as you soon will get there.

Comment: @bobbym Thank you. :-)